# Windows prevent multiple instances code not working

Tags: c++, windows, multiple-instances

I am using CreateEvent to prevent multiple instances of my application:

```
CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, "MyEvent");
if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
{
    // Do Stuff
    return FALSE;
}
```

However, at startup I have noticed that this doesn't work:
After the desktop is shown I automatically run a batch script that attempts to launch multiple instances of my program. The batch script succeeds and I can indeed see multiple instances.

Investigation so far:

- OutputDebug shows that each instance does not get `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`
- ProcessExplorer.exe shows that each instance was able to get a handle to the event "MyEvent".

Can anybody think why this might be happening, and how I could solve it?

Answer (score 1):

We use the function below, which is in our common utility DLL.  The method is derived from a Microsoft article explaining how to prevent multiple instances in WIN32.

```
#define STRICT
#include <stdheaders.h>

HANDLE   ghSem;

BOOL IExist( LPSTR lpszWindowClass )
{
   HWND     hWndMe;
   int      attempt;

   for( attempt=0; attempt<2; attempt++ )
   {
      // Create or open a named semaphore.
      ghSem = CreateSemaphore( NULL, 0, 1, lpszWindowClass );
      // Close handle and return NULL if existing semaphore was opened.
      if( (ghSem != NULL) && 
          (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) )
      {  // Someone has this semaphore open...
         CloseHandle( ghSem );
         ghSem = NULL;
         hWndMe = FindWindow( lpszWindowClass, NULL );
         if( hWndMe && IsWindow(hWndMe) )
         {  // I found the guy, try to wake him up
            if( SetForegroundWindow( hWndMe ) )
            {  // Windows says we woke the other guy up
               return TRUE;
            }
         }
         Sleep(100); // Maybe the semaphore will go away like the window did...
      }
      else
      {  // If new semaphore was created, return FALSE.
         return FALSE;
      }
   }
   // We never got the semaphore, so we must 
   // behave as if a previous instance exists
   return TRUE;
}
```

Just do something like this in your WinMain:

```
if( IExist("MyWindowClass") )
{
   return 1;
}
```

Of course, you could replace the return with whatever you need to do when you are not the first instance (such as activating the existing instance).